# Looking to call method with parameter to take in specified text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a Windows Form Application and I want to create a method to be able to pass in a specified text box from a _Click event. Such as below: My Method is AddTo() and I want to call from the 2 click events which have 2 separate text boxes. I want to be able to pass in the correct text box.

```
 void AddTo(string ctrl)
            {
                int num= int.Parse(ctrl);
                num++;
                ctrl = num.ToString();
            }
private void btnAddLevel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddTo(TextBox1.Text);
        }
private void btnAddSecond_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddTo(TextBox2.Text);
        }
```

I am pretty new to C#, is this possible to do? Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE:
Here is the full code with the fix below

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txtName.Text = "0";
        }

void AddTo(ref TextBox tBox)
    {


        if (tBox.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            int num = 0;

            //CHECK IF THE TEXT IS CONVERTIBLE TO NUMBER
            if (int.TryParse(tBox.Text, out num))
            {
                num++;
                tBox.Text = num.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnAddUnit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddTo(ref txtName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass textbox as an argument?

Comment: Yeah I want to basically pass in to "replace" 'ctrl' in the method with the textbox.text. Really what this does is just add 1 to the current value of the specified textbox.

Comment: What error do you get.

Comment: No error, it just doesn't do anything when I click the button. The value of the box does not increase with each button click as it should. It does work if I repeat the method code in each click even, which is exactly what I don't want to do, so I know the method code works when the textbox is explicitly stated.

Comment: Try the code posted. Hopefully that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ref` key word to retain data updates for passing objects.

Try below code:

```
        //YOUR TEXTBOX IS A REFERNCE HERE. SO THAT THE UPDATES ARE RETAINED
        void AddTo(ref TextBox tBox)
        {
            //VALIDATED YOUR TEXT BOX IF DATA EXISTS BEFORE UPDATING
            if (tBox.Text.Trim().Length > 0 )
            {
                int num = 0;
                //CHECK IF THE TEXT IS CONVERTIBLE TO NUMBER
                if (int.TryParse(tBox.Text, out num))
                {
                    num++;
                    tBox.Text = num.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

While calling

```
//USE REF WHILE CALLING
 AddTo(ref textBox1);//textbox object
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I had to run out for a bit but will try when I get back and will update!

Comment: When using your code, I am getting:
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to 'string'

Comment: Did you change you function signature to void AddTo(ref TextBox tBox)

Comment: Yes I did. I got that part working but when I try to pass the named textbox in the click event, it does not do anything. The value in the box does not increase as it should from num++

Comment: Are you calling like this "AddTo(ref textBox1);" in click event and still not happening??

Comment: Ok. I am suspecting another thing.... Very first you do not have anything and it is not incremented to 1.... I guess??

Comment: Here is the click event code:                                                             
private void btnAddUnit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AddTo(ref txtName);

        }

Comment: I do have a text property set for the textbox of '0'

Comment: Better set it in form load..... something like this ... textBox1.Text="0";

Comment: Is there anyway you can show your form code somewhere?

Comment: I removed the text property and set it in the form load. Still nothing though. But when I put the code manually in the click event for the button, it works fine.

Comment: Can you try replacing "ref" with "out" in both places

Comment: When I replace 'ref' with 'out' in both spots I get this: Error CS0177 The out parameter 'tBox' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

Comment: Actually the ref is working for me and text box is getting update. Could you post the whole code some where?

Comment: You initialized txtlevel in form1 and passing txtname in button click.... Please fix it.  Set txtName.Text ="0"; in form1 constructor

Comment: Fixed. Sorry typo, same result though.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made a new form to test your code and it worked. I deleted the textboxes and added new ones and it worked too.